# GWT: Is Timer the only way to keep my app up-to-date with the server?

Tags: gwt

I just got asked to reduce the traffic made by my GWT app. There is one method that checks for status.

This method is an asynchronous call wrapped in a Timer. I know web apps are stateless and all that, but I do wonder if there is some other way to do this, or if everyone has a Timer wrapped around a call when they need this kind of behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out [gwteventservice](http://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/). It claims to have a way to push server events and notify the client.

I have a feeling they might be implemented as long running (hanging) client to server RPC calls which time out after an interval (say 20sec), and then are re-made. The server returns the callback if an event happens in the meanwhile.

I haven't used it personally but know of people using it to push events to the client. Have a look at the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/wiki/StartPage) . If my assumption is correct, the idea is to send an RPC call to the server which does not return (hangs). If an event happens on the server, the server responds and that RPC call returns with the event. If there is no event, the call will time out in [20 seconds](http://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/wiki/Configuration). Then a new call is made to the server which hangs in the same way until there is an event.

What this achieves is that it reduces the number of calls to the server to either one for each event (if there is one), or a call once every 20 seconds (if there isn't one). It looks like the 20 sec interval can be configured.

I imagine that if there is no event the amount of data sent back will be minimal - it might be possible to cancel the callback entirely, or have it fail without data transfer, but I don't really know.

Here is another resource on [ServerPush](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/ServerPushFAQ) - which is likely what's implemented by gwteventservice.

Comment: small question about server-push. The idea of it is to ALWAYS send calls, but only return something when there is a change, correct?

Comment: I've updated my answer. In essence you should only get an event/response when something happens on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Running on Google app engine you could use they Channel technology

http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/appengine/docs/java/channel/overview.html

Answer (score 1):

If you need the client to get the status from the server, then you pretty much have to make a call to the server to get it's status.

- You could look at reducing the size of some of your messages
- You could wind back the timer so the status call goes out less often
- You could "optimise" so that the timer gets reset when some other client/server IO happens (i.e. if the server replies you know it is ok, so you don't need to send the next status request).

Comment: cool, simple answer, does not tell me to use another technology, and indicates I'm not crazy XD